# FAIL: protobuf-test

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake libtool curl make g++ unzip
https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/latest
git clone https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf.git
cd protobuf
git submodule update --init --recursive
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make check
```

---

make check failed on (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS,Intel® Core™ i3-2330M CPU @ 2.20GHz × 4 ,OS type 64-bit,Memory 3.8 GiB) with following summary:

```
FAIL: protobuf-test
PASS: protobuf-lazy-descriptor-test
PASS: protobuf-lite-test
PASS: google/protobuf/compiler/zip_output_unittest.sh
PASS: google/protobuf/io/gzip_stream_unittest.sh
PASS: protobuf-lite-arena-test
PASS: no-warning-test
============================================================================
Testsuite summary for Protocol Buffers 3.18.0
============================================================================
# TOTAL: 7
# PASS:  6
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  1
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0
============================================================================
See src/test-suite.log
Please report to protobuf@googlegroups.com
============================================================================

make[3]: *** [Makefile:8176: test-suite.log] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/gunjan/protobuf/src'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:8284: check-TESTS] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/gunjan/protobuf/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:8400: check-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gunjan/protobuf/src'
make: *** [Makefile:1913: check-recursive] Error 1
```

Why make check is failing for protobuf-test?
Is this related to memory?

Comment: "protobuf-3.18.0" : Did you get these build requirements ? → `dh-elpa zlib1g-dev libgmock-dev libgtest-dev python3-all libpython3-all-dev python3-setuptools python3-six xmlto rake-compiler` Ref. https://packages.debian.org/source/experimental/protobuf

Comment: One answer https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/7860 says `Yes enlarged the memory and it worked.` ......... Another comment is `When you execute 'make check', the maximum memory usage reaches 8.6g`

Answer (score 0):

1.sudo chmod +777 -R protobuf;
2.sudo make check.